# VS2017 Unable to start debugging. Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

Working with xamarin forms, I have recently updated my android version from 7.1 to 8.1 (even though I don't understand why this might have messed up anything) but I can't run the app anymore in debug mode (it compiles and runs perfectly in release).

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Unable to start debugging. Could not load file or assembly 'libadb,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=___' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea why this might be happening? I have tried looking for online solutions but couldn't find any that fits my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like libabd is a dependency that is missing.  Something might have went wrong in the upgrade process.  

Can you search your computer for libabd.dll?  If its only in debug mode, I would guess that libabd opens some kind of debug tunnel.

Comment: It seems that one of the dependencies (libabd) was not referenced properly in your project. At some point VS was able to find it and copy it to the bin folders, but it can no longer find it. It seems that the release bin folder still has it, so it run properly there, but perhaps somebody cleaned the debug bin folder so it no longer has it. As a temporary measure, you can copy the libadb file(s) from the release bin folder to the debug bin folder. But you need to find the library and reference it correctly.

Comment: Right now I'm feeling it is because Xamarin is a bad platform and we should never use it. But I have to make it work so I will let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, after also upgrading from 7.1 to 8.1 my settings were changed, apparently. So the fix was easy. Go to the android project, make sure your debugger is set to Xamarin, not C++ in debug mode. I am not sure why it was changed.

[image]

Hope it helps.